# Socket.io close connection immediately when change tab safari IOS

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**The bug**

socket closes connection immediately when i switch tabs using Safari on IOS

socket client version:

> 4.5.1

socket server version

> 4.5.1

**To reproduce the bug**

Open socket connection in safari, change tab to another app

---

The connection comes back after I go back to the tab, but that's bad

I'm using a ping pong, but the connection at the same time I change the tab

Comment: Do you mean that the server actually gets a disconnect on the socket when you switch tabs?  Or do you mean that your ping/pong back and forth just stops when you switch tabs?  I ask because browsers are doing all sorts of things to stop background tabs from chewing up battery life and one of the things they do is limit what timers and sockets can do in the background.

Comment: At the exact moment I switch tabs, the client disconnects, it seems that the browser closes the connection

this doesn't happen if I use websocket, only if I use socket.io

This doesn't happen on android, both websocket and socket.io